# ORA-01435: user does not exist when accessing V$Locked_Object in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to run below query from `SOME_USER`

`SELECT * FROM V$Locked_Object;` -- Public Synonym

also tried

`SELECT * FROM "SYS"."V_$LOCKED_OBJECT";`

and getting.

```
ORA-01435: user does not exist
01435. 00000 -  "user does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have given these grants from `SYS` to `SOME_USER`

`grant select on "SYS"."V_$LOCKED_OBJECT" to SOME_USER;` still getting the same error.

I noticed that I am able to access other public synonyms in `SOME_USER` like `V$LOCK_ACTIVITY`, `v$lock_type` etc. getting this error when trying `V$Locked_Object` and `V$LOCK` only. Please suggest maybe I am missing some basics.

Oracle Version - `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: you speak all the time about `SOME_USER`, but you grant to `AUTOMATION_DG_DB`. is that the same user?

Comment: @hotfix yes, I wrote that by mistake. edited the question now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to check against metadata.

First, check whether the object exists in the DB at all (I'm sure it exists, but still for double checking).

I hope you have access to dba_% objects

```
select * from dba_objects where object_name like 'V%LOCKED%OBJ%';
```

Then, check if you have the permissions to access that object

```
select * from all_objects where object_name like 'V%LOCKED%OBJ%';
```

If the object exists in the dba_ table and can not be found in all_ it means you don't have the permissions for that. Execute the following for double checking

```
select * 
  from user_tab_privs 
 where table_name like 'V%LOCKED%OBJ%';
```

You'll get probably nothing here as you can't find the object, so the next thing I'd check is the role name that has access to that particular object

```
select * 
  from role_tab_privs
 where table_name like 'V%LOCKED%OBJ%';
```

Then, check if you have that role assigned to your user

```
select * from session_roles
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

use 
select * from "SYS"."V$locked_objects"

Comment: I don't this there is any such object in my DB getting `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`